# How to add user defined rfh2 headers in Apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, jms, ibm-mq, jbossfuse, switchyard

Hi all I need to send a metadata xml in rfh2 headers.can you please tell me how can I do it using switchyard or Apache camel.

Answer (score 0):

If they are standard JMS-style message headers, they will just come across. If they are embedded in the RFH2 handler, you'll need a special processor.

Media Driver's Managed Bridge does this. Designed as a IBM MQ adapter for reading messages from IBM MQ transmit (XMIT) queue, it automatically moves the data to standard headers.

https://mediadriver.com/managedbridge/

Disclaimer: I head up product development for Media Driver